# Field-level encryption in quarkus mongodb panache

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-panache

i am trying to facilitate field-level encryption with quarkus mongodb panache, but struggle to find a guideline or example.

- Is it possible to en-/decrypt specific fields with quarkus mongodb panache?
- Or does a converter exist that i can attach to a field and implement the encryption inside the converter?
- Or is it possible to provide quarkus mongodb panache with a specifically configured MongoClient to use the mongodb "client side encryption"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quarkus creates the MongoClient for you and make it available via CDI.

MongoDB with Panache uses this MongoClient.

There is currently no way to provides an `AutoEncryptionSettings` for the creation of this MongoClient so Client Side Encryption cannot be used.

You can open an [enhancement request](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/new?assignees=&labels=kind%2Fenhancement&template=feature_request.md&title=) to Quarkus to provides a way to configure client side encryption for MongoDB. But be aware that this will not currently work in native mode as the mongocrypt library needed for client side encryption is a native library so will not works OOTB with GraalVM native images.