# Client-Side Field Level Encryption in native mode with Quarkus

Tags: mongodb, encryption

We would like to use the MongoDB Client-Side Field Level Encryption with Quarkus running in native mode.
On the link [Using the MongoDB Client - Quarkus](https://quarkus.io/guides/mongodb) we found that
“Currently, Quarkus doesn’t support Client-Side Field Level Encryption in native mode.”

I suppose that the problem is that “the mongocrypt library needed for client side encryption is a native library so will not work OOTB with GraalVM native images”. ([Field-level encryption in quarkus mongodb panache - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65669209/field-level-encryption-in-quarkus-mongodb-panache))

If that is the problem, then as I understand it should be possible to use explicit encryption, because the mongocrypt library is only used at automatic encryption. Can somebody confirm this?

Comment: I have no idea what Quarkus is, but looking at the link you provided it appears it is using Java.  CSFLE was introduced in MongoDB 4.2.  The minimum version of the Java MongoDB driver to support 4.2 including CSFLE is 3.11.  I am not clear which MongoDB Driver version Quarkus uses.

Answer (score 0):

> because the mongocrypt library is only used at automatic encryption

it's not true. Any encryption requires mongocrypt library (ie libmongocrypt). Automatic encryption additionally requires a spawned mongocryptd process that is completely different thing